# iOS mail client submits form with wrong method

Tags: html, ios, forms, email

I have e-mail dispatch with feedback form in my app. Something like this:

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
    <some stuff here>
</form>
```

All clients and services are OK, except iOS mail client - it submits form using GET method instead of POST(probably, just ignoring method attribute).
Any ideas why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to have a suitable answer, please edit your question and include further details.

Comment: Thanks, Pier, but there is no additional details - form is simple like ABC and issue only in wrong method while submitting form.